# Rename file in Linux if file exist in a single command

Tags: linux, shell, command

There is need that I want to rename file in Linux if file exist in a single command.

Suppose I want to search test.text file and I want to replace it with test.text.bak then I fire the following command

**find / -name test.text**
if it exist then I fire the command
**mv test.text test.text.bak**

In this scenario I am executing two commands but I want this should be happen in single command.

Thanks

Comment: skip the `find` part...

Comment: You might want to use some version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Just:

```
mv test.text test.test.bak
```

If the file doesn't exist nothing will be renamed.
To supress the error message, when no file exits, use that syntax:

```
mv test.text test.test.bak 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Will this solution work if `test.text` be not in the current directory?

Comment: By "work" do you mean will it find some other file than the one you are telling it to find in the current directory? Of course not.  `mv` simply examines the file name parameter; if you say `mv path/to/file.txt path/to/file.txt.bak` then it will look in `path` in the current directory and then `to` inside that.  If you use an absolute file name, it will use that.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, ur right, but how the question is written: "then I fire the command mv test.text test.text.bak", I think the op won't search a whole directory structure, only a file inside the current working dir.

Comment: @chaos Suppressing the error message is one thing; but still mv returns with a non-zero exit code if test.text doesn't exist; which might or might not be what you want to happen.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find `test.txt` somewhere in a subdirectory of `dir` and move it, try

```
find dir -name test.txt -exec mv {} {}.bak \;
```

This will move all files matching the conditions.  If you want to traverse from the current directory, use `.` as the directory instead of `dir`.

Technically, this will spawn a separate command in a separate process for each file matched by `find`, but it's "one command" in the sense that you are using `find` as the only command you are actually starting yourself.  (Think of `find` as a crude programming language if you will.)

Comment: You can add `-maxdepth 1` to only search the current directory, though that's a bit of a crock.

Answer (score 1):

```
for FILE in `find . -name test.test 2>/dev/null`; do mv $FILE $FILE.bak; done
```

This will search all the files named "test.test" in current as well as in child direcroties and then rename each file to .bak

Comment: This runs multiple commands, by any useful definition, and will fail on files whose names contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters. The simplest, most robust fix is probably to switch to `find -exec mv` but then that duplicates my answer.